# Goodreads Api : Book review parsing : Iframe in the XML : How to remove that Iframe?

Tags: iframe, xml-parsing

I wanted to remove the review section content from XML response I received from the goodreads api and display it.
It seems like its an Iframe.
SO any idea how to do this ??

```
<reviews_widget>
<![CDATA[
<style>
    #goodreads-widget { font-family: georgia, serif; padding: 18px 0; width:565px; } #goodreads-widget h1 { font-weight:normal; font-size: 16px; border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB596; margin-bottom: 0; } #goodreads-widget a { text-decoration: none; color:#660; } iframe{ background-color: #fff; } #goodreads-widget a:hover { text-decoration: underline; } #goodreads-widget a:active { color:#660; } #gr_footer { width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid #BBB596; text-align: right; } #goodreads-widget .gr_branding{ color: #382110; font-size: 11px; text-decoration: none; font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; }
</style>

<div id="goodreads-widget">
    <div id="gr_header">
        <h1><a href="http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2657.To_Kill_a_Mockingbird">To Kill a Mockingbird Reviews</a></h1></div> <iframe id="the_iframe" src="http://www.goodreads.com/api/reviews_widget_iframe?did=DEVELOPER_ID&amp;isbn=0061120081&amp;links=660&amp;min_rating=&amp;review_back=fff&amp;stars=fff&amp;text=000" width="565" height="400" frameborder="0"></iframe> <div id="gr_footer"> <a href="http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2657.To_Kill_a_Mockingbird?utm_medium=api&amp;utm_source=reviews_widget" class="gr_branding" target="_blank">Reviews from Goodreads.com</a>
    </div>
</div>
]]>
</reviews_widget>
```

Comment: The Goodreads API [review method](http://www.goodreads.com/api#review.show) returns simple XML, so I don't understand why it would be sending an iframe. Are you using the developer API or some sort of plugin to retrieve the XML? Can you post a link where this is happening?

Comment: API Link : http://www.goodreads.com/book/title.xml?&key=YOUR-KEY&title=java 
It returns an embedded widget in the XML format containing Iframe .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the answer for this, though its just a simple solution ; may break :(
But will work temporarily.

```
            Label lb2 = new Label();
            string st = html;

            int stindex, endindex;
            string subst;
            stindex = st.IndexOf("<iframe");
            endindex = st.IndexOf("</iframe>") + 9;
            int lin = st.LastIndexOf("</iframe>") + 9;
            while ((endindex <= lin) && (stindex > 0))
            {
                subst = st.Substring(stindex, endindex - stindex);
                lb2.Text = subst;
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lb2);
                st = st.Substring(endindex);
                stindex = st.IndexOf("<iframe");
                endindex = st.IndexOf("</iframe>") + 9;
            }
```